# chrome.tabs.executeScript only seems to execute in the active tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have the following code in a background.js.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {

        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            file: 'inject.js'
        });

  } // if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
});
```

But when I change tabs the inject.js only runs in the active tab even if an inactive tab gets updated.  In the inject.js I have an automated process running for a particular website and it's clicking through some pages looking for specific text.  I want it to continue running on that one tab even if I open a new tab. But as soon as I change tabs the injection happens only on the active tab.  I thought tab.tabId or tabId would be for the tab that was updated but it seems like it's always the active tab.

Is there a way to figure out what tab updated so I can pass the correct tabId to executeScript?

Here is what my manifest looks like:

```
{
  "name": "Automated test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Nope, executeScript runs where it should. The problem is that the site scripts stop in inactive tabs. BTW if this onUpdated code is all you have, you can simply [declare a content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) instead.

Comment: Yeah, I was playing around with content script some too.  It just seems like if I start opening tabs everything runs where I am active though I want it to keep running on the one tab.  I could easily be missing something with content scripts as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, @wOxxOm led me to what I needed. I did need a content-script and the reason why I think I wasn't seeing the results I was expecting is that I was failing to remove and re-add my extension.  Sometimes it seems like it respects the changes made but maybe when you make changes to the manifest you need to remove and re-add the extension.

Once I did that it is correctly working on the inactive tab.